# Facebook API not retrieving event cover

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cover

Im using the javascript SDK to request some information from facebook, and when i try to request an specific event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event the cover photo is not been retrieved even when the event has one.

I have tried on Graph Explorer and the results are the same, no cover photo

Is this a bug? do I need the user_events permission?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you have to explicitely tell facebook api which fields you want to retrieve like this: 
/?fields=id,cover,description,end_time,is_date_only,name,owner,place,start_time